# Word-Macro: Oracle DB Connection

Tags: oracle, vba, ms-word

I need a Word Macro, that connects to an Oracle-Dateabase, gets some information and puts it into my Document.

Step one is to connect to the Database. I found the following code on http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=2071

```
'--------------------------------------
' create and open connection
'--------------------------------------
Dim oCn As New ADODB.Connection
oCn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
"Server=myserver;" & _
"Uid=gh_pc;" & _
"Pwd=gh_pc"

'---------------------------------------
' open recordset
'---------------------------------------
Dim oRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set oRs = oCn.Execute("SELECT * FROM pc_ficha_clinica")
While Not oRs.EOF
Debug.Print oRs.Fields(0).Value
oRs.MoveNext
Wend
'---------------------------------------
' cleanup
'---------------------------------------
oCn.Close
Set oRs = Nothing
Set oCn = Nothing
```

This is not working because it is missing the reference to ADOB.Connection. The following error appears (for me its German, I'm translating it here).

`The User defined Type is not declared`

I need to know how to Reference this OR how else to connect to the Database. If it is not possible to connect to an Oracle Database using a Word Makco I would like to know that as well.

---

**EDIT** Solution found by Dirk Vollmar and Wernfried Domscheit:

Tools - References - add `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects`

Hint for those who can not click the Reference option: Go to `Run->Reset` and Try again

Comment: I hope the user has read only privileges to a limited series of tables. Doesn't this strike you as a security issue?

Comment: The Database user has limited rights on only a few tables (Select only). I'll be trying to make the database login non-clear text and the makro maybe even pwd saved. But that is another problem that I will be taking care of later. I am sure there are ways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you still need to add a reference to the ADO library. You can do that via the *Tools -> References...* menu of the VBA editor.

Their you need to pick the *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects* library in the version you want to use (and any dependent assemblies as well).

Comment: I found that on the internet already, sadly i was not able to find the Tools-Menu. There is one Icon with the Tooltip (german: Werkzeugsammlung) Toolcollection, that is grayed out.

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/214952-tools-references-always-grayed-out.html `Make sure you're not in Break Mode. Try clicking Run->Reset. And now?` Didnt solve the problem for me.

Comment: @Luke You can download and install ADO from the Microsoft website, for example https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793. There are various versions. And here's a list of what it contains, generally. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675795(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Embarrassing ... Sorry and Thanks! :) The grayed out part was the wrong icon ~ I found the correct menu now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the ADODB library.

Go to menu Tools -> References -> Select "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.7 Library" (or whatever version you like to use or have)

Comment: See Dirk Vollmar 's Comments. Thanks for your help.